# WindowsAndroid will not start anymore

Tags: android

I'm running Windows 7 Professional (SP1). When I startup the program (either directly from the "android" exe in the program folder, or the Start Menu shortcut, the command line shows 3 paragraphs of errors about failure to startup, all with error code 2. Then the Windows 7 Program Advisor notes that the program crashed, and 'attempts' to fix the problem. I originally installed WIndowsAndroid to my thumb drive under D:/Downloads/WindowsAndroid, where it worked. I then attempted to install it to my PC's hard drive, which created the WindowsAndroid startup errors. I then uninstalled both the hard drive and USB programs, as they both showed the errors, and then reinstalled to my thumb drive (this time, D:/Downloads/WAndroid), but the errors kept occuring. As of now, the program is installed on the root of my device (the Android.exe file is located on D:/SocketeQ), and when executed, the startup errors commence.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the windows compatibility mode or run as administrator. Some times it will work.

Comment: I tried running as admin and using compatibility mode, but the errors keep happening. Thanks for trying, though :)